# php bb smiley replacement

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to replace text smileys with image versions using my mysql database

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    function bbcodeParser($bbcode) {

        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smileys");
        while( $smiley = mysql_fetch_array($sql) ) {
            $match[$smiley['match']] = $smiley['match'];
            $replace[$smiley['match']] = "<img style='max-height: 25px; max-width: 25px;' src='" . $smiley['replace'] . "' />";
        }

        /* Parse */
        $bbcode = preg_replace($match, $replace, $bbcode);

        /* Return parsed contents */
        return $bbcode;
    }
?>
```

but when I use

> bbcodeParser("this is a test :)");

nothing is shown, not even the basic text

my database is:

```
"  match |                    Replace                        "
--------------------------------------------------------------
"   :)   | http://mysite.com/images/smileys/icon_e_smile.gif "
"   XD   |   http://mysite.com/images/smileys/icon_lol.gif   "
etc....
```

Comment: Are you `echo`ing the results of your function call anywhere? Or just calling it?

Comment: if you use `return`, you have to `echo` it. Also, I wouldn't recomment doing the query within the function, rather search for the text, and then pass it to bbcodeParser(). Also, mysql_ functions are deprecated. Use a library instead, such as MySQLi or PDO

Comment: I am using echo phpcodeParser($post['content']);

Comment: @VinnyBenson - `echo phpcodeParser($post['content']);`? But your function here is called `bbcodeParser()`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm stupid about the mysql_query within the function, scratch that.

Comment: yea sorry I meant bbcodeparser :)

Comment: `:)` is not a valid regular expression

Comment: I got it working, see Orangepill's answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values in your match array are not valid preg patterns. Use str_replace instead.

```
$bbcode = str_replace($match, $replace, $bbcode);
```

or you can forgo building the $match array and use

```
$bbcode = str_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $bbcode);
```

Answer (score 2):

`$match` should be a pattern string (or an array of pattern strings). Here it seems to be an array with equivalent key and value (why ?!).

See more at http://php.net/preg_replace .

Comment: Arrays containing regular expressions work. Your array does not contain regular expressions.

Comment: @Vinny Benson: They do but definitely not this way.

Comment: I knew that, I spent 20 mins trying to make it work, I forgot about str_replace until Orangepill mentioned it :)